# Question about creating and managing Django apps

Tags: python, django

I'm completely new to Django. I'm on macOS Sierra.  
I've installed Django using `pip3 install django`. I currently have a folder that will be used to contain all of my Django apps that I create in the future. 
Right now when wanting to create a new project I use:   
`cd desktop`, `cd django_apps`, `mkdir (dirname)`, `cd (dirname)`, `virtualenv env`, `source env/bin/activate`, `django-admin.py startproject (projectname)`   
The problem occurs when I try use `python manage.py runserver`, where I get an ImportError saying `ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`.  
How I normally solve this is by then going into the project folder and using `pip3 install django` again.  
Is there a way for me to install Django into the django_apps folder so that all apps have access and I don't need to install Django into every one of the new apps I create?

Edit:
Found all that was needed was to change `django-admin.py startproject (projectname)` to `django-admin.py startproject (projectname) .`

Comment: Your django package will be stored where your env is created. You should create env first then install django package

Comment: There is a reason why you would like to have each project with its own environment (called dependency hell ) you can always have requirements.txt file and install all packages listed in it. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#using-requirements-files

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read the Djangogirls tutorial. 

https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

Comment: @BenjieSS its not django-admin.py, its django-admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, mere installing django will not work. You have to create a django project and then create a django app. Please follow this:

```
django-admin startproject mysite .
```

The above command shall create a django project named 'mysite'. Now

```
cd mysite
```

Then create a django app inside your django project. To do this run this command

```
django-admin startapp app
```

The above command shall create a django app named 'app' inside your django project named 'mysite'.
Now you will need the following command to create database migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Now you will have to finall migrate your database which is nothing but creating a database for your django project. To do this run the following command

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Now at this stage you are good to run your favourite command , :) to run the server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Now visit 127.0.0.1:8000 and voila! Your server is running.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Just wondering what do both commands 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' actually do, the makemigrations tends to return 'No changes detected'. Also does this work across separate projects and therefore separate websites as well i.e. different URLs will be used for different projects.

Comment: Hope i answered your question, you may mark the answer as correct.